# JSAPI documentation: where did it go?

Tags: java, web, documentation, speech-recognition

I'm trying to access java.sun.com so I can read their documentation on speech recognition here:
http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-guide/

Unfortunately, I cannot access this page or any other page under java.sun.com...

Is it just my computer that's having problems with this?  Or is their site down?

Does anyone have a copy of this documentation they could share?  Or an idea on when the site will be back online?

I've looked online for answers on these and I couldn't find anything.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, you're aware that `Sun` was acquired by `Oracle`. You still can reach the cached version of this page [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cache%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fjava.sun.com%2Fproducts%2Fjava-media%2Fspeech%2FforDevelopers%2Fjsapi-guide%2F). Lots of links from sun.com were broken.

To get the version of page cached by `Google` you can either enter `cache:<YOUR_URL_HERE>` in the address bar (assuming you're using `Google Chrome`) or copy-paste the URL into the google search box, and then navigate to the cached version from the search results.

**Edit**
OK, that was lazy me 4 hours ago ;) I did a little research and that's what I found out:

- [Official Oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html)
- [JSR-113 JavaTM Speech API Specification](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=113)
- Since Java Speech API is only a specification, you could find more information from concrete implementations. See [FreeTTS Programmer's Guide](http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/ProgrammerGuide.html) for example (for a whole list of implementations refer to FAQ mentioned above).
- And while I was typing this Edit, I could tell you for sure that the link you mentioned in the original post was available for a couple of minutes :)

Comment: Hello!  Thank you very very much!! :)

Yes, I was aware.  I'm using google chrome so it shouldn't be to hard to access the cached pages!  I don't know why I didn't think of using cached pages on my own XP

Okay!  So, I believe I am all set! :)  Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Also, the documentation is still available online from time to time. At the moment, I'm able to access it at the URL you provided in the original post =)

Comment: Checked it again. It's alive!

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has this technology [tucked away here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-138153.html).  There is also [a FAQ about it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html).

Since this is only a specification, you need to grab an implementation.  According to (Sun) Oracle, [these are the implementations of note,](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jsapifaq-135248.html#implementation) probably prior to the migration.  Who knows which implementations are actually maintained these days, as JSAPI doesn't seem to have been included into 1.7 (maybe it will get into 1.8?)

Answer (score 1):

Here I found the documentation:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/speech/forDevelopers/jsapi-doc/javax/speech/recognition/package-summary.html